# Help with proof of necessary conditions for A(rectangle) < A(rectangle) when P(rectangle) > P(rectangle)

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

Motivation: I was discussing an algorithm with a friend, when he mentioned that it could be used to calculate both the minimum area enclosing rectangle and the minimum perimeter enclosing rectangle of a set of points.
For me, the fact that the minimum perimeter and the minimum area enclosing rectangle may be the same seemed very counter-intuitive and, although I believed what our sources was saying, I tried to come up with this result by myself first without searching out how or trying some counter examples.

I'm not very good with proofs, so although I arrived at something that seems ok, but I have my doubts about it, so I'm asking if this is correct.

So, my thoughts on how can you increase the perimeter and decrease the area were:

If we have a rectangle with sides $a$ and $b$ and we change the sizes increasing its perimeter, you have:

$2a + 2b < 2(a+d1) + 2(b+d2),  a > 0, b > 0$

Where $d1$ and $d2$ are the changes in both $a$ and $b$.

From this, you have:

$d1 + d2 > 0$

In order for this two happen, you need:

$d1 > 0$ and $d2 > 0$

or $d1 > 0$ and $d2 = 0$ (or swap d1 with d2)

or $d1 > 0$ and $d2 < 0$ and $|d1| > |d2|$ (or swap d1 with d2)

Since the area is $ab$, on the first two cases the area would increase, so the only possible one is the third.

We would have them:

$ab < (a+d1)(b+d2)$ with $d1 > 0$ and $d2 < 0$

$d1*(b+d2) > -a*d2$

Since $b*d1 > (b+d2)*d1$ (because $d2 < 0$) , we have:

$b*d1 > -a*d2$ (This actually being the step where I'm mostly sure about)

$ d1/(-d2) > a/b $

So: $|d1/d2| > |a/b|$ and $d2 < 0$ are sufficient conditions for having a greater perimeter with a lesser area.

This seems to work. But is this correct?
Also, could a more strict condition be achieved if I hadn't used the step that I mentioned I'm unsure about? (Does $|d1/d2| > |a/b|$ and $d2 < 0$ implies that the perimeter will be greater and the area smaller, but it's not an "if and only if"?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the algorithm out of curiosity?

Comment: @NotNotLogical Rotating Calipers (http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~orm/rotcal.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want the old area ab to be bigger than the new area.  So it should be

$$ab > (a+d_1)(b+d_2)$$

That is going to throw everything onward off.

Just to clear things in my mind I decided to make both d's positive and then adjust for the sign in the problem.  So I have  $d_1 > d_2 > 0 $.

The inequality above then becomes.

$$ ab > (a+d_1)(b-d_2) $$

Now unfortunately the result is not a nice as you'd want but here it is.

$$\begin{eqnarray} 0> -a d_2 + d_1 b - d_1 d_2 \\ a d_2 + d_1 d_2 > d_1 b \\ a > \frac{d_1}{d_2} b - d_1 \end{eqnarray} $$

There it is.  Not very pretty but it does work.  Consider $a = 5, b =4$  If we take $d_1 = .1$ and $d_2 = 0.07$ then area will increase.  Since $\frac{0.1}{0.07} \cdot 4 - 0.07 = 5.644$ But if we instead choose $d_2 = 0.08$ then $\frac{0.1}{0.08} \cdot 4 - 0.08 = 4.92 <5$  A quick check shows that $5.1 \cdot 4.92 <20$.

Comment: Well, that was silly :(
I stated it incorrectly and thought about it for a long time, haha.

Anyway, the way I described should show a condition for the area to grow when the perimeter grows then, right?
But, with $a=10$, $b=5$, $d1=10$, $d2=-4$,
we have: $P = 30$, $A = 50$ and $P' = 42$, $A = 20$ (the perimeter went up, but the area went down.. even though $10/4$ > $10/5$).
Where did I make a mistake then? :(